# Replacing rusted steel post with 6 x 6 x 6 pressure treated lumber

Tags: repair

I have a finished sun porch that is resting on 4 - 4" X 6' round steel post.

The base of these post were buried under dirt for several years and have rusted. A couple of the post have about a 1" hole near the base plate.  I tried to get this fixed professionally, but the estimates have come in around $3500 to replace the existing steel posts.

I was wondering if I could replace these using 6" X 6" x 6' pressure treated lumber.
 The porch is 12' x 13', glassed in with a roof and tile floor, so I am assuming that it weighs quit a lot.

Will the pressure treated lumber withstand the weight?
[image: Other Post][image: Rusted Post]

[image: Porch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to says thanks for the advice.  I was able to replace all the steel post successfully and without too much trouble.  I did build 2' deep piers for each post, 8 inches in diameter.   Each pier took two bags of 50lbs concrete. On these I places a 6x6 post base with bolt secured into the concrete.I use a jack to slightly raise the porch floor so I could remove the existing post and install the new ones.  Taking my time I did each post one at a time.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Excellent work and the proper way to do it.

Comment: Well done, indeed! Thanks for coming back with an update on what you did. Just make sure you click the check-mark next to your answer so the system won't bump it to the top every few months. You also get a couple of bonus internet points, redeemable for unicorns and rainbows! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will bear the weight. Your porch is a typical use case for such posts, and the span between is also typical. Just be sure they're rated for below-grade use.

Comment: Does below grade use imply that I will be burying them or should I place them on a concrete pier above the ground?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's really up to you. I assumed they were in the ground (at least somewhat) now.